# AWS EMR Hive partitioning unable to recognize any type of partitions

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, hiveql

I am trying to process some log files on a bucket in amazon s3.

I create the table :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE apiReleaseData2 (
messageId string, hostName string, timestamp string, macAddress string DISTINCT, apiKey string,
userAccountId string, userAccountEmail string, numFiles string)
ROW FORMAT
serde 'com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.JsonSerde'
with serdeproperties ( 'paths'='messageId, hostName, timestamp, macAddress, apiKey, userAccountId, userAccountEmail, numFiles')
LOCATION 's3://apireleasecandidate1/regression/transferstatistics/2013/12/31/';
```

Then I run the following HiveQL statement and get my desired output in the file without any issues. My directories are setup in the following manner :

s3://apireleasecandidate1/regression/transferstatistics/2013/12/31/ < All the log files for this day >

What I want to do is that I specify the LOCATION up to the  's3://apireleasecandidate1/regression/transferstatistics/' and then call the

```
ALTER TABLE <Table Name> ADD PARTITION (<path>)
```

statement or the

```
ALTER TABLE <Table Name> RECOVER PARTITIONS ;
```

statement to access the files in the subdirectories. But when I do this there is no data in my table.

I tried the following :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE apiReleaseDataUsingPartitions (
messageId string, hostName string, timestamp string, macAddress string, apiKey string,
userAccountId string, userAccountEmail string, numFiles string)
PARTITIONED BY (year STRING, month STRING, day STRING)
ROW FORMAT
serde 'com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.JsonSerde'
with serdeproperties ( 'paths'='messageId, hostName, timestamp, macAddress, apiKey, userAccountId, userAccountEmail, numFiles')
LOCATION 's3://apireleasecandidate1/regression/transferstatistics/';
```

and then I run the following ALTER command :

```
ALTER TABLE apiReleaseDataUsingPartitions ADD PARTITION (year='2013', month='12', day='31');
```

But running the Select statement on the table gives out no results.

Can someone please guide me what I am doing wrong ? 
Am I missing something Important ?

Cheers 
Tanzeel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HDFS anyway, the partitions manifest in a key/value format like this:

```
hdfs://apireleasecandidate1/regression/transferstatistics/year=2013/month=12/day=31
```

I can't vouch for S3 but an easy way to check would be to write some data into a dummy partition and see where it creates the file.

ADD PARTITION supports an optional LOCATION parameter, so you might be able to deal with this by saying

```
ALTER TABLE apiReleaseDataUsingPartitions ADD PARTITION (year='2013', month='12', day='31') LOCATION 's3://apireleasecandidate1/regression/transferstatistics/2013/12/31/';
```

Again I've not dealt with S3 but would be interested to hear if this works for you.